# Howto manage freeing single pointers from a double-pointer block

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I have a block of pointers to some structs which I want to handle (i.e. free) separately. As an example below there is an integer double-pointer which should keep other pointers to integer. I then would like to free the second of those integer pointers (in my program based on some filterings and calculations). If I do so however, I should keep track of int-pointers already set free so that when I iterate over the pointers in the double-pointer I do not take the risk of working with them further. Is there a better approach for solving this problem (in ANSI-C) without using other libs (e.g. glib or alike)?
Here is a small simulation of the problem:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    
    int **ipp=NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int *ip = malloc(sizeof (int));
        printf("%p -> ip %d\n", ip, i);
        *ip = i * 10;
        if ((ipp = realloc(ipp, sizeof (int *) * (i + 1)))) {
            ipp[i] = ip;
        }
    }
    printf("%p -> ipp\n", ipp);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d. %p %p %d\n", i, ipp + i, *(ipp+i), **(ipp + i));
    }
    // free the middle integer pointer
    free(*(ipp+1));
    printf("====\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d. %p %p %d\n", i, ipp + i, *(ipp+i), **(ipp + i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which prints something like

```
0x555bcc07f2a0 -> ip 0
0x555bcc07f6f0 -> ip 1
0x555bcc07f710 -> ip 2
0x555bcc07f6d0 -> ipp
0. 0x555bcc07f6d0 0x555bcc07f2a0 0
1. 0x555bcc07f6d8 0x555bcc07f6f0 10
2. 0x555bcc07f6e0 0x555bcc07f710 20
====
0. 0x555bcc07f6d0 0x555bcc07f2a0 0
1. 0x555bcc07f6d8 0x555bcc07f6f0 0
2. 0x555bcc07f6e0 0x555bcc07f710 20
```

Here I have freed the middle int-pointer. In my actual program I create a new block for an integer double-pointer, iterate over the current one, create new integer pointers and copy the old values into it, `realloc` the double-pointer block and append the new pointer to it, and at the end free the old block and all it's containing pointers. This is a bit ugly, and resource-consuming if there is a huge amount of data, since I have to iterate over and create and copy all the data twice. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just set it to `NULL` after freeing and when working with pointers check if they are `NULL` before doing anything

Comment: Re: _"a bit ugly, and resource-consuming if there is a huge amount of data, since I have to iterate over and create and copy all the data twice."_.  Have you considered changing your program to use a [linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/)?  Deleting a node, then re-adding a node is a natural and commonly used feature of `lists`

Comment: @ryyker Node's data is still dynamically allocated and must be managed. Hence this wouldn't solve the problem, instead adding an extra overhead of using other dynamically allocated memory (the list itself).

Comment: From your last sentence it appeares you are asking for suggestions after citing the very maladies that _Linked Lists_ could address.  Are you trying to get away from dynamic allocation altogether?  Or is the purpose of your post to determine how to make it less cumbersome to maintain changing memory usage during run-time?  Replacing your current architecture with _link Lists_ only simplifies what you are attempting to do, i.e. there is no need to move, or copy memory, and certainly no need to use `realloc()`.  (which is often misapplied, as in your example code.)  (@Vlad shows the correct way)

Comment: Aside - Also it is not necessary to use `realloc()` when allocating new memory on a pointer that has already been freed.  `realloc()` is useful when needing to preserve the contents in a particular area of memory, while expanding its size.  If that is not a need (which is not in this case) `malloc` or `calloc` are sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Re:

> *"This is a bit ugly, and resource-consuming if there is a huge amount of data, since I have to iterate over and create and copy all the data
> twice. Any help is appreciated."*

*First observation*: It is not necessary to use `realloc()` when allocating new memory on a pointer that has already been freed. `realloc()` is useful when needing to preserve the contents in a particular area of memory, while expanding its size. If that is not a need (which is not in this case) `malloc()` or `calloc()` are sufficient.  @Marco's suggestion is correct.

*Second observation*: the following code snippet:

```
    if ((ipp = realloc(ipp, sizeof (int *) * (i + 1)))) {
        ipp[i] = ip;
    }
```

is a potential memory leak. If the call to `realloc()_` fails, the pointer `ipp` will be set to null, making the memory location that was previously allocated becomes orphaned, with no way to free it.

*Third observation*:  Your approach is described as needing:

- Array of `struct`
- dynamic memory allocation of a 2D array
- need to delete elements of 2D array, and ensure they are not referenced once deleted
- need to repurpose deleted elements of 2D array

Your initial reaction in comments to considering using an alternative approach notwithstanding,  Linked lists are a perfect fit to address the needs stated in your post.

- The fundamental element of a Linked List uses a struct
- Nodes (elements) of a List are dynamically allocated when created.
- Nodes of a List are not accessible to be used once deleted. (No need to track)
- Once the need exists, a new node is easily created.

Example `struct` follows.  I like to use a *data* `struct` to contain the *payload*, then use an additional `struct` as the *conveyance*, to carry the *data*  when building a Linked List:

```
typedef struct {//to simulate your struct
    int dNum;
    char unique_name[30];
    double fNum;
} data_s;

typedef struct Node {//conveyance of payload, forward and backward searchable
    data_s data;
    struct Node *next; // Pointer to next node in DLL
    struct Node *prev; // Pointer to previous node in DLL
} list_t;
```

Creating a list is done by creating a series of nodes as needed during run-time.  Typically as records of a database, or lines of a file are read, and the elements of the table record (of element of the line in a file) are read into and instance of the data part of the `list_s` struct.  A function is typically defined to do this, for example

```
void insert_node(list_s **head, data_s *new)
{
    list_s *temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    //insert lines to populate 
    temp.data.dNum = new.dNum;
    strcpy(temp.data.unique_name, new.unique_name);
    temp.fNum = new.fNum
    //arrange list to accomdate new node in new list 
    temp->next = temp->prev = NULL;
    if (!(*head))
        (*head) = temp;
    else//...or existing list
    {
        temp->next = *head;
        (*head)->prev = temp;
        (*head) = temp;
    }
}
```

Deleting a node can be done in multiple ways.  It the following example method a unique value of a node member is used, in this case `unique_name`

```
void delete_node_by_name(list_s** head_ref, const char *name)
{
    BOOL not_found = TRUE;
    // if list is empty 
    if ((*head_ref) == NULL)
        return;
  
    list_s *current = *head_ref;
    list_s *next = NULL;
  
    // traverse the list up to the end 
    while (current != NULL && not_found) 
    {
        // if 'name' in node...
        if (strcmp(current->data.unique_name, name) == 0) 
        {
            //set loop to exit
            not_found = FALSE;
            //save current's next node in the pointer 'next' /
            next = current->next;
            // delete the node pointed to by 'current'
            delete_node(head_ref, current);
            // reset the pointers
            current = next;
        }
  
        // increment to next node
        else
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `delete_node()` is defined as:

```
void delete_node(list_t **head_ref, list_t *del)
{
    // base case 
    if (*head_ref == NULL || del == NULL)
        return;
  
    // If node to be deleted is head node 
    if (*head_ref == del)
        *head_ref = del->next;
  
    // Change next only if node to be deleted is NOT the last node 
    if (del->next != NULL)
        del->next->prev = del->prev;
  
    // Change prev only if node to be deleted is NOT the first node 
    if (del->prev != NULL)
        del->prev->next = del->next;
  
    // Finally, free the memory occupied by del
    free(del);
}
```

[This link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/) is an introduction to Linked Lists, and has additional links to other related topic to expand the types of lists that are available.

Answer (score -1):

You could use standard function `memmove` and then call `realloc`. For example
Let's assume that currently there are n pointers. Then you can write

```
free( *(ipp + i ) );

memmove( ipp + i, ipp + i + 1, ( n - i - 1 ) * sizeof( *pp ) );

*( ipp + n - 1 ) = NULL; // if the call of realloc will not be successfull
                         // then the pointer will be equal to NULL  

int **tmp = realloc( ipp, ( n - 1 ) * sizeof( *tmp ) );

if ( tmp != NULL )
{
    ipp = tmp;
    --n;
}
else
{
    // some other actions
}
```